# Iterated integral of product of functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove this:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)g(y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y $,

either in the context of the Lebesgue or the Riemann integral. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y)=x$, and let $g(x)=x$. Then the left hand side is 
$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x y\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{4}$, but the right hand side is $\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^2\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{3}.$